# Center image underneath text in button

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

i have this code for making 3 buttons

```
<style>
        .ui-grid-b .ui-input-btn {
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 18px;
        }
    </style>

 <fieldset class="ui-grid-b" style="margin:5px;">
                <div class="ui-block-a" >
                    <input type="button" value="OpenALL" onclick="OpenALL();">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b" >
                    <input type="button" value="OpenHash" onclick="OpenHash();">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c" >
                    <input type="button" value="OpenBUG" onclick="OpenBUG();">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

i need to add image to the button (under the text)

I tried all kinds of ways, but the Result was always ugly and not centered

I need the picture to be below the text and everything will be centered.

this is the JSfiddle (i dont know how to add images)

http://jsfiddle.net/goldsoft/ukbs8kxg/

i try this what suggest ezanker  and i see it not in center and what is the Round gray circle ?

http://jsfiddle.net/goldsoft/ukbs8kxg/

[image]

thanks

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link and a picture of what you want?

Comment: i update mu question with JSfiddle

Comment: You can use custom icons. Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ukbs8kxg/2/  Are you actually using jQM 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of search, I finally found a solution that worked properly.

CSS:

```
<style>
    .ui-grid-b .ui-input-btn {
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .button
    {
        background-image:url("url"); //I used a 16x16 image
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:bottom;
        padding-bottom:15px;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-b" style="margin:5px;">
            <div class="ui-block-a" >
                <input type="button" value="OpenALL" onclick="OpenALL();" class="button"/>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" >
                <input type="button" value="OpenHash" onclick="OpenHash();" class="button"/>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c" >
                <input type="button" value="OpenBUG" onclick="OpenBUG();" class="button"/>
            </div>
 </fieldset>
```

Here's final screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4d0uul